# PostgreSQL SHOW work_mem shows 16GB but configured to 1024MB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm working on a PostgreSQL 9.4 and wondering about my `work_mem`. If I query

```
show work_mem;
```

I get:

```
work_mem
text
16GB
```

However if I `grep` the config file (the file from `show config_file`) I get:

```
work_mem = 838860kB   # min 64kB
work_mem = 1024MB     # pgtune wizard
```

The only configuration option with 16GB is `temp_buffers`. What could change the `work_mem`value?

Comment: Maybe your user is configured to use `16MB`. You use `select name, setting, unit, source
from pg_settings
where name = 'work_mem';` to find out on which level the setting was changed. It could also be changed through `ALTER SYSTEM` then it would show up in `postgresql.auto.conf`

Comment: That `SELECT` gives me `work_mem | 16777216 | kB | configuration file`

Comment: Maybe the file was edited since the server was started. Does this change if you reload the config files using `select pg_reload_config()`

Comment: `SELECT pg_reload_conf()` returned `t` but `work_mem` is still 16GB. I copied the `postgresql.conf` to another plat and started another PostgreSQL (9.5 thou) and it gives me 1GB of `work_mem`.

Comment: It was the `postgresql.auto.conf` file after all. It just happened to be in a completely different folder (`/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main`) where the config file was (`/etc/postgresql/9.4/main`). You should convert your comment to an answer for others (future me :) to find more easily later.